# tga textures for psk/psa files

Tags: texturing, uv, import

I recently extracted some PSK/PSA files from an old Unreal Engine 2 game and I want to add them in Unity3d.
I can do everything except setting the correct texture on the body...

Here are the 3 files and a picture of how it should look:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q50ne1mya...mpire.zip?dl=0
[image: Vampire]

Comment: What is the question? Could you please edit your post and provide a phrase ending in a question mark? If you asking for someone to do it for you then that is probably best asked over at https://blenderartists.org

Comment: I could resolve my problem with 3DS Max, thanks anyway!